# JOIN - Returns 5 instead of 3 rows for repeating values in ID column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, inner-join

I have the following two tables:

Table A:

```
id|valA
--+----
1 | a
2 | b
2 | c
```

Table B:

```
id|valA
--+----
1 | A
2 | B
2 | C
```

What I expect to get using join is:

```
id|valA|valB
--+----+----
1 | a  | A
2 | b  | B
2 | c  | C
```

However, I get the following

```
id|valA|valB
--+----+----
1 | a  | A
2 | b  | B
2 | c  | B
2 | c  | C
2 | b  | C
```

I am using the following query:

```
select id, valA, valB from A
inner join B
on A.id = B.id;
```

How do I use the join to get the expected results?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You `id` value is not unique - ie it is not a suitable `key` to make a 1-1 join.

Answer (score 1):

Both tables have a duplicate ID of 2, so you get a result with all the possible combinations of the two rows in each table with that ID (bB, bC, cB and cC). If you can rely on the values, you can add them to the join condition:

```sql
SELECT a.id, valA, valB 
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.id = a.id and valA = LOWER(valB)
```

If you can't make this assumption, you could add a rank pseudocolumn to the values with the same ID and use in in the join condition too, although it may be a bit clunky:

```sql
SELECT idA, valA, valB
FROM   (SELECT id AS idA, valA, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valA) AS rankA
        FROM   a) a
JOIN   (SELECT id AS idB, valB, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valB) AS rankB
        FROM   b) b ON idA = idB AND rankA = rankB
```